# golang: [reflect.ValueOf unexpected] [fault address 0x0]

Tags: go

Panic occurs when using reflect.ValueOf.

The exception information is as follows：

```
unexpected fault address 0x0
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0xb1e31e]

goroutine 14253772 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x170e6a6?, 0x25c7948?})
    /root/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x5d fp=0xc006759d68 sp=0xc006759d38 pc=0x439f1d
runtime.sigpanic()
    /root/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:851 +0x28a fp=0xc006759dc8 sp=0xc006759d68 pc=0x4500aa
reflect.(*rtype).Kind(...)
    /root/go/src/reflect/type.go:823
reflect.unpackEface(...)
    /root/go/src/reflect/value.go:153
reflect.ValueOf(...)
    /root/go/src/reflect/value.go:3150
root/go/P2P/pkg/utils.InterfaceIsNIL({0x9afff2fa4f3386ff?, 0x26?})
    /root/P2P/pkg/utils/common.go:44 +0x9e fp=0xc006759df8 sp=0xc006759dc8 pc=0xb1e31e
root/go/P2P/node.(*Node).discoverMgt(0xc000490540, 0xc002f77c40?)
    /root/P2P/node/discoverMgt.go:61 +0x4e8 fp=0xc006759fc0 sp=0xc006759df8 pc=0x122b648
root/go/P2P/node.(*Node).TaskMgt.func5()
    /root/P2P/node/taskMgt.go:26 +0x2a fp=0xc006759fe0 sp=0xc006759fc0 pc=0x123956a
runtime.goexit()
    /root/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 +0x1 fp=0xc006759fe8 sp=0xc006759fe0 pc=0x46d881
created by root/go/P2P/node.(*Node).TaskMgt
    /root/P2P/node/taskMgt.go:26 +0x24a
```

The exception code is as follows, specifically in `va := reflect.ValueOf(i)`:

```
func InterfaceIsNIL(i interface{}) bool {
    ret := i == nil
    if !ret {
        defer func() {
            recover()
        }()
        va := reflect.ValueOf(i)
        if va.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            return va.IsNil()
        }
        return false
    }
    return ret
}
```

Complete code example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/rand"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p"
    dht "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-kad-dht"
    "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/crypto"
    "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/host"
    "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/peer"
    "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/peerstore"
    "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/protocol"
    "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/routing"
    drouting "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/discovery/routing"
    dutil "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/p2p/discovery/util"
    ma "github.com/multiformats/go-multiaddr"
)

const LocalAddress = "127.0.0.1"
const privatekeyFile = ".private"

const Rendezvous = "/rendezvous/1.0.0"

func main() {
    var port int
    flag.IntVar(&port, "port", 4002, "node listen port")
    flag.Parse()

    // boot node
    bootstrapPeer := "/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001/p2p/12D3KooWDKHV8Rp8qTttyiMxm83Dmzs4b1Pmv1b4E4mpcmrZWDhL"
    bootstrapAddr, err := ma.NewMultiaddr(bootstrapPeer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx1, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    ctx2, events := routing.RegisterForQueryEvents(ctx1)

    // golog.SetAllLoggers(golog.LevelDebug) // Change to INFO for extra info

    prvKey, err := identify_peer("", "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //
    host, err := libp2p.New(
        libp2p.Identity(prvKey),
        libp2p.ListenAddrStrings(fmt.Sprintf("/ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/%d", port)),
        libp2p.DefaultTransports,
        libp2p.DefaultMuxers,
        libp2p.DefaultSecurity,
        libp2p.NATPortMap(),
        libp2p.EnableNATService(),
        libp2p.EnableRelay(),
        libp2p.EnableRelayService(),
        libp2p.EnableHolePunching(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Host created. We are:", host.ID(), " ", host.Addrs())

    kademliaDHT, routingDiscovery, err := initDHT(ctx2, host, []ma.Multiaddr{bootstrapAddr})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _ = kademliaDHT

    go discoverPeers(ctx2, host, routingDiscovery)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case peer := <-events:
                for _, v := range peer.Responses {
                    if v != nil {
                        for _, addr := range v.Addrs {
                            if !InterfaceIsNIL(addr) {
                                fmt.Println(">>> Fount:", v.ID.String(), "addr: ", v.Addrs)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }()

    select {}
}

func discoverPeers(ctx context.Context, h host.Host, routingDiscovery *drouting.RoutingDiscovery) {
    fmt.Println("Searching for peers...")
    // Look for others who have announced and attempt to connect to them
    tick := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 5)
    for {
        select {
        case <-tick.C:
            //peerChan := kademliaDHT.FindProvidersAsync(ctx, cid.Cid{}, 1)
            peerChan, err := routingDiscovery.FindPeers(ctx, Rendezvous)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("FindPeers err: ", err)
                continue
            }
            var ok = true
            var peer peer.AddrInfo
            for ok {
                select {
                case peer, ok = <-peerChan:
                    if !ok {
                        break
                    } else {
                        fmt.Println("++++++++Found peer: ", peer)
                    }
                    if peer.ID == h.ID() {
                        continue // No self connection
                    }
                    err := h.Connect(ctx, peer)
                    if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println("++++++++Failed connecting to ", peer.ID.Pretty(), ", error:", err)
                    } else {
                        for _, addr := range peer.Addrs {
                            h.Peerstore().AddAddr(peer.ID, addr, peerstore.PermanentAddrTTL)
                        }
                        fmt.Println("++++++++Connected to:", peer.ID.Pretty())
                    }
                }
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
            }
        }
    }
}

func initDHT(ctx context.Context, h host.Host, boots []ma.Multiaddr) (*dht.IpfsDHT, *drouting.RoutingDiscovery, error) {
    var options []dht.Option
    options = append(options, dht.V1ProtocolOverride(protocol.ID("/dht/protocol/test")), dht.Resiliency(10), dht.Mode(dht.ModeAutoServer))
    // Start a DHT, for use in peer discovery. We can't just make a new DHT
    // client because we want each peer to maintain its own local copy of the
    // DHT, so that the bootstrapping node of the DHT can go down without
    // inhibiting future peer discovery.
    kademliaDHT, err := dht.New(ctx, h, options...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    if err = kademliaDHT.Bootstrap(ctx); err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, peerAddr := range boots {
        peerinfo, _ := peer.AddrInfoFromP2pAddr(peerAddr)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            err := h.Connect(ctx, *peerinfo)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Failed to connect to bootstrap node: ", err)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Connected to the boot node: ", peerinfo.ID.String())
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    routingDiscovery := drouting.NewRoutingDiscovery(kademliaDHT)
    dutil.Advertise(ctx, routingDiscovery, Rendezvous)
    return kademliaDHT, routingDiscovery, nil
}

// identify reads or creates the private key file specified by fpath
func identify_peer(workspace, fpath string) (crypto.PrivKey, error) {
    if fpath == "" {
        fpath = filepath.Join(workspace, privatekeyFile)
    }

    fstat, err := os.Stat(fpath)
    if err == nil {
        if fstat.IsDir() {
            fpath = filepath.Join(fpath, privatekeyFile)
        } else {
            content, err := os.ReadFile(fpath)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            return crypto.UnmarshalEd25519PrivateKey(content)
        }
    }

    // Creates a new RSA key pair for this host.
    prvKey, _, err := crypto.GenerateKeyPairWithReader(crypto.Ed25519, -1, rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    f, err := os.Create(fpath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    b, err := prvKey.Raw()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    _, err = f.Write(b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = f.Sync()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return prvKey, nil
}

func InterfaceIsNIL(i interface{}) bool {
    ret := i == nil
    if !ret {
        defer func() {
            recover()
        }()
        va := reflect.ValueOf(i)
        if va.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            return va.IsNil()
        }
        return false
    }
    return ret
}
```

I think this situation should not occur in go. If I already know that the parameter is nil, then why should I use IsNil() to judge?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (i.e. include the input that causes `InterfaceIsNIL` to panic).

Comment: Check the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/methods/11) about interfaces - they hold two things: a `value` and a `type` and both can be nil. I am guessing that the value part of the `i` in Your code is set to nil.

Comment: Pretty much the test for `nil` may be failing due to a classic problem described in tha FAQ: https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error

Comment: @frode The only reason, that I can imagine _could_ cause `reflect.ValueOf` to throw a panic, is if the argument passed to it was either deallocated or modified by a separate process; which could happen, _especially inside loops_, if the variable is "mismanaged". You need to review your `TaskMgt` and `discoverMgt` code, and any other related code, to make sure that memory isn't shared irresponsibly. For example in your `initDHT` you definitely have the aforementioned problem. See also https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: @kostix the panic originates from the Go reflect package, not from the OP code. It looks like there's somthing `unsafe` going on

Comment: This exception is not easy to reproduce and only occurs occasionally when there are a large number of nodes. The number of nodes in my actual project is more than 800.

Comment: @mkopriva After this value is taken out from the events channel, only this thread is processing it, and no other place will affect it.

Comment: is there a race condition in the code or hardware issue for memory? I found some other issues related to `unexpected fault address 0x0`.